# How to fix permissions on Gimp to save and export under user directories on Windows

Tags: windows-10, gimp

I have a fresh install of GIMP on Windows 10. When I try to save an image in the native format in a folder under `Users\username` I get an error like:

*GIMP Message: Error creating 'C:\Users\nagev\Documents\test.xcf': Error opening file “C:\Users\nagev\Documents\test.xcf”: No such file or directory*

I also get other errors exporting images as JPG or PNG. I can save files under `C:\Downloads`, though.

Weirdly, Inkscape, also a new install, seems to have a similar issue, I get *"File not found. Check the filename and try again".*

Then I used the classic "*Paint*" program and I can edit and save files to the exact same location. It looks like a permissions issue, but I'd expect it to work properly out of the box. Is this the expected behavior for Windows users and is there a proper way to fix it (without running as Administrator)? By the way, I have used GIMP before on Ubuntu, and was able to save and export easily, without any permissions gymnastic. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a problem with that particular directory? How about `C:\Users\nagev\Pictures`? (it should be the same directory, `Documents\My Pictures` is a link)

Comment: I had the same issue with Documents, but I just tried with `Download` and it works, so it's clearly a permissions issue, which I'd still like to fix. I don't have this issue with other applications. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with "controlled folders"--a Windows feature to prevent ransomware attacks. The folder you are trying to save to is included as a "controlled folder". Go to 'Settings' and search for "Controlled folder access". You can then either turn the feature off (not recommended), remove the concerned folder from the controlled folders list, or create a new folder outside the controlled folders list (a 'working' folder) to which you can save your work without any issue.

Comment: Exactly that! Interestingly I found other programs like Audacity in the allowed list that I don't remember adding manually. My guess is that at some point Windows prompted me for access but for some reason it didn't for GIMP. Thanks.